# how to get access_token instagram api in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I'm trying to connect my website to instagram using [instragram-ruby-gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem) and [this tutorial](http://blog.ajmalafif.com/instagram-gem-with-rails/) .

In step 5, inside Instagram.rb in config/initializer

```
require "instagram"

    Instagram.configure do |config|

    config.client_id = "client_id goes here"

    config.access_token = "access_token goes here"

    end
```

How can I get an access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look here http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/ and here you can try to get access token http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/ ,
also it may be useful for you http://symmetricinfinity.com/2013/04/06/download-your-likes-from-instagram.html